# How to disable few columns of a row based on a condition in Webix datatable

Tags: datatable, webix

I have a webix datatable with column names as 'No.', 'Name', 'Action', 'Phone', 'Comments'. Below are the types of the columns :

1. 'No.' and 'Name' columns are always readonly.
2. Rest three 'Action', 'Phone' and 'Comments' are editable plus cells under 'Action' and 'Phone' columns are having dropdown menus.

Requirement:
Lets say, for a particular value in 'Name' field (for example 'Mark') , I want to disable all the editable fields of that particular row. Either the row should rendered as disabled(readonly) or just before editing the editable fields would turn disabled(readonly).  All other rows should have their usual behavior.

I have tried to achieve this with onBeforeEditStart event here at https://webix.com/snippet/3bafd99c

However I am facing issues to implement it. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code like next

```
onBeforeEditStart:function(id){
     return this.getItem(id).id1 !== "Mark";
}
```

https://webix.com/snippet/306471fc

The getItem call returns the current row, and next check compares the value of name column with a control one. ( using id:"name" in columns's config will make the above line much more readable )

Comment: Thanks first of all. I asked the feature for name == Mark just to ask the requirement in simpler words. If I want to check a lot of stuff in a checkAccess function and return true or false & then based on that return I want to disable the cells, is that possible ? I mean just the way I have done it in my snippets.